# Pandas (with def and np.where): error with values in a dataframe row conditioned on another dataframe row

Tags: pandas, function, where-clause, valueerror

I have dataframes A of shape XxY with values and dataframes B of shape ZxY to be filled with statistics calculated from A.

As an example:

```
A = pd.DataFrame(np.array(range(9)).reshape((3,3)))
B = pd.DataFrame(np.array(range(6)).reshape((2,3)))
```

Now I need to fill row 1 of B with quantile(0.5) of A columns where row 0 of B > 1 (else: np.nan). I need to use a function of the kind:

```
def mydef(df0, df1):
    df1.loc[1] = np.where(df1.loc[0]>1,
                          df0.quantile(0.5),
                          np.nan)
    pass

mydef(A,B)
```

Now B is:

```
    0   1   2
0   0.0 1.0 2.0
1   NaN NaN 3.5
```

It works perfectly for these mock dataframes and all my real ones **apart from one**.
For that one this error is raised:

*ValueError: cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value*

When I run the same code without calling a function, it doesn't raise any error.
Since **I need to use a function**, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. I erroneously had the same label twice in the index. Essentially my dataframe B was something like:

```
B = pd.DataFrame(np.array(range(9)).reshape((3,3)), index=[0,0,1])
```

so that calling the def:

```
def mydef(df0, df1):
df1.loc[1] = np.where(df1.loc[0]>1,
                      df0.quantile(0.5),
                      np.nan)
pass
```

would cause the condition and the if-false lines of np.where to not match their shapes, I guess.

Still not sure why working outside the def worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @FranciscoMariaCalisto I've corrected my question and expanded the answer to make it clearer, thanks

Comment: Great work, congratulations! With your edited answer, we can now understand the scope issue of the problem that you are trying to solve.